# How to set a DrawableLeft to an EditText with PasswordToggleEnabled

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-design-library

I've made a `TextInputEditText` for a `PasswordField` with a `DrawableLeft` as an icon, and then i added a `PasswordToggleEnabled(true)` .. this operation has deleted or hiden my `DrawableLeft`, Here's my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:passwordToggleContentDescription="Show Password"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        android:id="@+id/signupPasswordlayout"
        app:passwordToggleTint="@color/edittexttint">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:hint="Password"
            android:id="@+id/signupPassword"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:drawableTint="@color/edittexttint"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

so , is it possible to show both ( `PasswordToggle` and `DrawableLeft` ? ) thank you!

Comment: Change the attribute to `drawableStart`, instead of `drawableLeft`.

Comment: Works perfectly! , would you please put your _comment_ as an `Answer` so i can give u a **+1** :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd not seen this exact behavior before, but looking at the source for `TextInputLayout`, it does attempt to preserve the user-set drawables when it applies the placeholder drawable for the password toggle. However, like most everything else in the support libraries to which its applicable, it handles them with relative positions - i.e., `start` and `end` - rather than absolute - `left` and `right`.

The support libraries have always been notorious for breaking anything that specifies absolute directions or positions, so it's no surprise that that's the issue here, as well.

Simply change the attribute you're setting to `drawableStart`, instead of `drawableLeft`. Keep this in mind, too, for anything else involving a choice of absolute or relative positions and directions with the support libraries.